# In R with two raster layerss that differ in size and extent how to copy the smaller onto the larger?

Tags: r, r-raster

I have two raster layers with the same resolution and CRS but different extents. The larger has values that are all NA and it's extent is larger than the smaller.  I want to copy the smaller onto the smaller. Actually I have 30 or so smaller ones and eventually I want to create a stack.

I would like to do this with high level commands/functions but merge and overlay all appear to do different things or have restrictions such as identical origins.

Large raster info UTM coordinates.

```
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 650585.3 
xmax       : 653000.3 
ymin       : 4745829 
ymax       : 4748292 
ncol  805
nrow  821
res   3 3
```

Small raster typical info

```
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 651389.3 
xmax       : 653000.3 
ymin       : 4746414 
ymax       : 4748010 
ncol  532
nrow  507
res   3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes this works since my larger raster values are all NA and there's nothing to overwrite.

```
r <- extend(largeRaster, smallRaster, NA)
```